# Can't get BASH script to fill in password

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, samba

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 server VM via Hyper-V that is setup as a media server. I have a shared drive on my Server 2012 OS that I want to mount in Ubuntu at startup.

Right now, I can get it to mount by typing `sudo smbmount //host_ip/media ~/media`

Once that is typed in, I am prompted for the password for the share, which when entered, mounts the drive correctly.

I have written a script, but cannot get it to write the password when prompted.

- Is there a way I could write a simple BASH script and have it run at startup with root privilege?
- How can I have the script to fill in the password?

Comment: Can you show us your script (obviously hide your password/details)? That way, we can add suggestions for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Usually permanent mounts get set up in the [filesystems table file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab) (`/etc/fstab`). When the OS boots, all mounts specified in `/etc/fstab` are created. Here's some info from Ubuntu on [how to permanently mount Windows shares](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently).

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy if you have `expect` installed.

Here's an example using `expect`. Source - [GeekStuff](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/)

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 20
set ip [lindex $argv 0]
set user [lindex $argv 1]
set password [lindex $argv 2]

spawn ssh "$user\@$ip"

expect "Password:"

send "$password\r";

interact
```

Execute the above expect program as shown below.

```
guest@host1 $ ./ssh.exp 192.168.1.2 root password
spawn ssh root@192.168.1.2
Password:
Last login: Sat Oct  9 04:11:35 2010 from host1.geetkstuff.com
root@host2 #
```

Comment: As I mentioned... this is a very simple script...
But what I have so far is:

#!/bin/bash
echo "*** Mounting Share ***"
echo ""
sudo smbmount //192.168.1.176/media ~/media
echo""
expect "Password: "
send "mysecretpassword"
echo ""

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel points, a good way to mount a Samba share at startup is putting the share name on the /etc/fstab file.

The "one-liner" for getting it mounted at boot would be:

//hostname/share /mnt/samba smbfs username=user,password=password 0 0

The last two parameters should be zero. They are used for local filesystems only and are related to the use of dump command and the order thatfsck should be executed.